# Should static methods modify an object or return a new one

Tags: c#, .net, oop, static, instance

Let's say that there's a struct `Foo` of 8-16 bytes. It has a static method to `Add()` all its values to another struct and performance is paramount. I have seen many static methods like the one below:

```
public static Foo Add(Foo fooA, Foo fooB)
{
    var newVar = fooA.Var + fooB.Var
    return new Foo(newVar);
}
```

I've measured that it can be made faster by only referencing the arguments:

```
public static Foo Add(ref Foo fooA, ref Foo fooB)
{
    var newVar = fooA.Var + fooB.Var;
    return new Foo(newVar);
}
```

Fair enough. But **would it be confusing** if I avoided creating a new instance and instead modified the first argument?

```
public static void Add(ref Foo fooA, ref Foo fooB)
{
    fooA.Var += fooB.Var;
}
```

I haven't been able to formulate my question as eloquently as I'd like, but I hope it will be understood.

Edit:
Or perhaps, if something like this is needed, the method shouldn't be static in the first place. Is that a correct assertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example will definitely be faster because .net framework doesn't copy your parameters as it does when they are "byval". This technique is used when all kind of performance gains are needed. It is obvious that "byref" is faster than "byval".

Your method can be static or instance, if you use "ref" there is no copying of memory, and in your case it is a struct which is a value type.

Comment: I understand what `ref` is. The third case is the fastest, because I avoid allocating any additional memory. I guess my question is: Should I keep it as static, or would it be better served as an instance method?

Comment: It doesn't matter as far as being right or wrong. It is all depends on your design!!!

Comment: And I'm trying to base my design on something that people expect, not something obscure, hence why I asked here.

Comment: Your third example is fine. May be needs to be clearer as naming goes. XML commenting can help for the client to understand what it does. But definitely, example 1 and 2 are clearer for the user than example 3.

Comment: I thought so. I'm going with an instance method in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It's not confusing, but you're getting different results. In the second case you're altering one of the inputs and maybe you don't want that.

This behavior is called [Side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) and it's a real pain sometimes. This is a good reason one would use functional programming (less side effects) instead of imperative languages.

Comment: You mean the third case, correct? The second case has no side-effects.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I refer to the third case. It depends on what you're trying to do, but most of the time it's a bad idea to modify your parameters.